# Resolution for forces

Tags: mechanical-engineering, statics

[image: question]

I'm stuck trying to find the resultant of the force system. Here it is said to find the angle θ the resultant manes with the horizontal. But θ here is narked relative to F₂. How do I find the resultant and θ

Comment: It's asking for the angle of theta **for which the resultant is vertical** This is just a trigonometry simultaneous equation

Answer (score 3):

In order for the Resultant force to be vertical you only need the sum of the horizontal components of $F_1$ and $F_2$ to be zero

$$F_{1x} - F_{2x} =0 $$
$$F_{1}\cos(70) - F_{2}\cos\theta =0 $$

$$\cos\theta=\frac{F_{1}}{F_{2}}\cos(70) - F_{2} $$

$$\theta=\arccos\left(\frac{F_{1}}{F_{2}}\cos(70) - F_{2}\right) $$

if you substitute you should get
$$\theta=50[deg]$$

And the resultant R should be :

$$F_{1y} + F_{2y} =R $$
$$F_{1}\sin(70)+ F_{2}\sin(50) =R $$
$$R \approx 1077 [lb]$$

Comment: What theory guides add the forces & equating them to zero, since it's not stated that the forces are in equilibrium

Comment: It is stated that *the resultant of the two forces is vertical*, which indicates that the horizontal portion of the forces is in equilibrium.

Comment: The question is about the resultant of the forces. If you are thinking about the reaction from the bracket, then this will be determined by the load.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have time to type this up nicely - thought it would be quicker to write out by hand but in hindsight my handwriting is terrible. Let me know if you can't read anything!

[image]

Comment: There seem to be an error in the resultant R

Comment: You're totally right - I must have mashed the buttons on my calculator weirdly. Hopefully you can work out the correct value from the addition before it!

Comment: I have done a quick photoshop update to correct the final value or R!

Answer (score 1):

A problem with meaningful solution must have a key with enough conditions/constraints, that make it soluble. As a problem solver, we need to find/identify the key and the associated conditions/constraints. Sometimes work a problem in the backward manner can be helpful. The steps are as follows:

1. Expand the unknown (R = ?) to a more detailed expression. That is, in an orthogonal grid system,

R = (Fx^2 + Fy^2)^1/2; in which, Fx = F1cos70 + F2cos(\theta), and Fy = F1sin70 + F2sin(\theta)

2. Identify/find the key. In this problem, the angle (\theta) is the key, and the statement that says "Determine the angle (\theta) which makes the resultant (R) of the two forces **vertical**, is the furnished condition/restraint. Laterally the statement tells us to find the angle (\theta) that will result in: sum Fx (horizontal resultant force) = 0, so the relationship can be expressed as,

Fx = F1cos70 + F2cos(\theta) = 0

Now you have the key to solve the problem. Hope this helps.